# Hooks for Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, hook

We have a process during new hire onboarding that requires managers and/or ops teams to spend time creating and giving permissions to employees. Recently, we have been thinking that it would be nice for us to automate this process, i.e., through a script of sorts.

A good indication that someone has recently joined our team (under some organization), would be if it exists, for our Active Directory to post some event to some server.

So my question is, does AD have support for hooks or any sort of automation that developers can tap into?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set up all the required permissions to a group and then just add the newcomer to the group?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17055.active-directory-event-ids-when-a-new-user-account-is-created.aspx) about
Active Directory creating an event upon user creation. 
Then you can attach a task to the event. [This](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-passing-parameters-to-event-triggered-schedule-tasks/) blog entry explains in a detailed way how to pass parameters to the powershell script defined in the task - it involves manipulating the xml export of the task itself to insert the XPath query of an event detail.

Or, depending on the size of your organization, you could query a dynamic group in which all user objects are retrieved, and work on the delta from a previous run.